# Taylor expansion of the gradient: how to use big O notation?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, approximation, approximation-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function and let $\nabla f$ be its gradient. I am interested in approximating this gradient around some point $x_0$ using a Taylor expansion such that
$$
\nabla f(x)=\nabla f(x_0)+\nabla^2 f(x_0)(x-x_0)+O\left(||x-x_0||^2\right)
$$
where $||x-x_0||$ is some norm of $x-x_0$, and where $\nabla^2 f$ is the Hessian matrix of $f$. Is this expansion correct? Does it matter which norm I use?

If the expansion is correct, how should we think of the vector $O\left(||x-x_0||^2\right)$? If $n=1$, this notation means that there exists $M>0$ and $\delta>0$ such that
$$\left|O\left(||x-x_0||^2\right)\right|\leq M||x-x_0||^2$$
for all $|x-x_0|<\delta$. But how does this work when $n>1$? Does that condition hold element by element? If so, are the $M$'s and $\delta$'s the same across elements?

EDIT: Fixed the expansion

Comment: Proofread your Taylor expansion. No, the estimate in terms of the lengths of the vectors.

Comment: What is wrong with the Taylor expansion? Do you mean the norm of $O$ is the object that is bounded?

Comment: It should be $\nabla^2f(x_0)(x-x_0)$ not $\nabla^2f(x_0)x$. And no, the choice of norm is irrelevant (all norms on a finite-dimensional vector space are equivalent, i.e generate the same topology). And for big $O$, just put norms $\|\cdot\|$ instead of absolute values. If you want, you can do it component by component, or you can do it using the Euclidean norm on $\Bbb{R}^n$ or any other norm (like I said above, all norms on a finite-dimensional space are equivalent). You will of course need to fiddle around the $M$’s and $\delta$’s if you change norms (just take suitable min/max of them).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks! I thought the term in $O$ should be one order higher than the expansion. See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Calculation_of_Taylor_series. Is that not the case?

Comment: Oh lol… embarrassing mistake. I was mixed it up with little oh. Yea assuming $f$ is smooth enough, what you wrote is fine.